# Trying to validate whether or not the user typed in Yes or No

Tags: java, while-loop, boolean-logic

So I am trying to validate whether the user typed in a Yes or No and to continue asking until they type in one or the other.  This is my code so far.

```
System.out.println("Would you like a Diamond instead of a Pyramid? Type Yes or No");        
String input2 = scan.nextLine();
boolean d = input2.equals("Yes");
System.out.println(d);

while ((d != false) ||  (d != true)) {
    System.out.println("Invalid Input. Please try again");
    input2 = scan.nextLine();
    d = input2.equals("Yes");
    System.out.println(d);
}
```

Where am I going wrong? I am new to java. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: I am awful at writing. What I am going for is this type of logic.
Ask the user if they would like a diamond instead of a pyramid.
a. The user must type “Yes” or “No”.
b. If the user types neither of these, ask again until they provide appropriate input.

Comment: I'm removing the Javascript tag; Java and Javascript are unrelated languages. It's also good to include what's going wrong in your question -- the symptom, as it were. You've described what you want, and you gave some code, but you didn't actually say what the problem is. That said, try working out what `d != false || d != true` evaluates to for each of `d`'s two possible values.

Comment: Sounds like my a prodject leader I have :). "Can you do this?", me: "no", he: "Invalid Input. Please try again"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are ending up having an infinite loop at

```
while ((d != false) ||  (d != true))
```

since `d` being a `boolean` even when updated would either be `true` or `false` and in both the cases would satisfy the above condition. Instead you can change it to

```
System.out.println("Would you like a Diamond instead of a Pyramid? Type Yes or No");        
String input2 = scan.nextLine();
boolean d = input2.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes") || input.equalsIgnoreCase("No"); // confirms if the user input is Yes/No or invalid other than that
.... 
while (!d) { // d==false ' invalid user input
    System.out.println("Invalid Input. Please try again");
    input2 = scan.nextLine();
    d = input2.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes") || input.equalsIgnoreCase("No");
    System.out.println(d); 
    // also printing a boolean would print either true or false base on your input; you migt want to perform some other action
} // this would exit on user input "Yes"
```

Answer (score 0):

Booleans can ONLY equate to true or false so your while loop is going to execute no matter what because d will be true or it will be false.  I think you want to just do

```
while (d != true)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using or(||) operator in your conditions whenever user typed one of your condition is false and other is true so that's why its not working fine.
if you want to stop asking at true value write below condition.

```
while(d != true)
```